# Rails.root from engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-engines

I'm having some problem accessing `Rails.root` from my rails engine, that I'm creating. I need to fetch a yml config file from the main app.

Is there any "best practices" for handling configurations for your engines?

Comment: did you try with `Rails.application.root`?

Comment: Yes and that's also nil.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's assume you have a module attribute for that.

```
# lib/my_engine.rb

module MyEngine

  mattr_accessor :app_root

end
```

Then you can load it from the initialize block like so:

```
# lib/my_engine/engine.rb

module MyEngine

  class Engine < Rails::Engine

    initializer "my_engine.load_app_root" do |app|

       MyEngine.app_root = app.root

    end

  end

end
```

Comment: For me, it had to be `initializer` instead of `initialize`.. (http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead use `Rails.root` use: `MyEngine::Engine.root` ;D

Comment: @dan-klasson where are you trying to access? Inside the main app or inside engine itself ?